# ValueError: could not convert string to float in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, decision-tree

I have a dataframe, on which i'm performing decision tree classifier. But I'm getting the below error

Sample dataset

```
 CUSTOMERID ACCOUNTTYPE TRANSACTIONSOURCE

 4          Savings     cash
 26         Current     cheque
 47         Current     wire
```

code so far:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz

merge4 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\anagha\\Desktop\\SynehackData\\DATA\\DATA\\merge4.csv")



merge4.dtypes

CUSTOMERID                int64
PRIMARYACCOUNTNUMBER      int64
BALANCE                   int64
SALARY                    int64
FIRSTNAME                object
MARITAL_STATUS           object
PRIMARYOCCUPATION        object
ACCOUNTTYPE              object
BANKCODE                 object
ACCOUNTID                 int64
cardtype                  int64
issuemonth                int64
issueyear                 int64
validuptomonth            int64
validuptoyear             int64
creditlimit               int64
cashlimit               float64
cardstatusid              int64
STATUS                   object
TRANSACTIONSOURCE        object
AMOUNT                    int64


trainData  = merge4.drop('ACCOUNTTYPE' , axis=1).values
trainLabel = merge4.ACCOUNTTYPE.values

 testData  = merge4.drop('ACCOUNTTYPE' , axis=1).values
 testLabel = merge4.ACCOUNTTYPE.values

 model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
 model.fit(trainData,trainLabel)
```

error :

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Cash'

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, do you now solve it?

```
 File "C:\Python35-64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '非星级'